# Why does this function return 0 even when assigned a value? (C)

Tags: c, function, return, return-value

Below is the code. When I test it, it keeps returning 0 for some reason.

```
float compute_personal_allowance ( float annualSalary ) 
{
    int pa = 0;
    if (annualSalary <= 100000)
        pa == 11850;
    else if (annualSalary > 100000)
        pa == 11850 - 1 * ((annualSalary - 100000)/2);
    return pa;
}
```

I test it using:

> gcc -lm -std=c99 -o

Comment: Aside from the issue with your using `==` rather than `=`, using a `float` for your allowance will mean that you'll have errors in the pence for someone with a 6 figure salary. Much better to work in pence throughout and use an integral type.

Comment: Try adding `-Wall` to your gcc command line, and the compiler will give warnings very related to exactly what the problem is.  In fact, make a habit of always using `-Wall`.

Comment: Have a serving of `-Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be complete: also the first assignment of `pa` is wrong:

```
float compute_personal_allowance ( float annualSalary ) 
{
    int pa = 0;
    if (annualSalary <= 100000)
        pa = 11850;
    else if (annualSalary > 100000)
        pa = 11850 - 1 * ((annualSalary - 100000)/2);
    return pa;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
pa == 11850 - 1 * ((annualSalary - 100000)/2);
```

`==` doesn't do assignment, it does comparison. So this doesn't actually do anything in this case. It evaluates to `1` or `0` and then just discards that result. What you need instead is

```
pa = 11850 - 1 * ((annualSalary - 100000)/2);
```